# Canada certificate program

Tags: canada, resident-permit, student-visa

I did my UG in engg from India and worked as media specialist for 1.5 years. Is it advisable to do a post graduate certificate program on Advertising - Creative & Digital Strategy from centennial or should I do masters. Will I get work permit after that. How about job opportunities.

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? Do you wanna settle down in Canada? or do you just want to study more? If you have want to settle down you might be able to qualify under the **Express Entry program**.

Comment: I would like to settle down in Canada.

Comment: Consider the express entry program that government of Canada provides. If you have enough points you might qualify for permanent residence in Canada. I'll post an answer in sometime giving you more details about this

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, I think you have a couple options.

## Option 1

You can apply for permanent residence under [Express Entry](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/express-entry/). 
It works on a [Comprehensive Ranking System (CRS)](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/express-entry/grid-crs.asp). Under this system, there are various factors considered to award you points. And based on this point system, CIC does 2 draws every month. If your points are over the cut off points, you will get an invitation to apply for permanent residence to Canada.

In this factors like *age, level of education, official languages proficiency, Canadian work experience* are considered. Moreover you can score extra points if you have a spouse or common law partner. The average points have been around 450-500 points recently. But its never sure.
I think your current job experience puts you in the category [1123 Professional occupations in advertising, marketing and public relations](http://www5.hrsdc.gc.ca/NOC/English/NOC/2011/ProfileQuickSearch.aspx?val=1&val1=1123) or [0124 Advertising, marketing and public relations managers](http://www5.hrsdc.gc.ca/NOC/English/NOC/2011/ProfileQuickSearch.aspx?val1=0124) category. However I am not too sure about this. Take a look at the link for more details.

## Option 2

This is a long journey to go but it is still an option. You can consider taking a masters program or a 2 year diploma program. I leave that decision to you. But after graduating you will be able to get a work permit and get a job in Canada. If everything works out for you, you can apply under provincial nomination which will give you 600 points in the CRS system. This is going to be a lengthy process because you will be studying and working for atleast 2 years. In any way you will need to apply under Express Entry to immigrate ASAP to Canada.